# Making a call to Google maps API's but getting empty response

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

I'm trying to communicate with Google trough cURL in Laravel 5.3. 
I get an empty response but a 200 status code.
Here's my code:

```
    public function directionGet($origin, $destination) {
    $callToGoogle = curl_init();
    $googleApiKey = '**************************';

    curl_setopt_array(
      $callToGoogle,
      array (
          CURLOPT_URL => 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='. $origin.'&destination=' . $destination . '&key= ' . $googleApiKey,
          CURLOPT_POST => true,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_HEADER => 0
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($callToGoogle);
    curl_close($callToGoogle);
    return response()->json($response); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your google map api key is configured as well in your google dev dashboard ?  https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using

Comment: I can recommend to use guzzle is very easy to use and read ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found few problems in your code
1. I think google required you use https instead http for security
2. $origin and $destination need encode for url format before send in curl
3. You have 1 space after $key

So you try this code

```
public function directionGet($origin, $destination) {

    $googleApiKey = '****************************';

    $url          = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='. urlencode($origin).'&destination=' . urlencode($destination) . '&mode=driving&key=' . $googleApiKey;

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => [
            "cache-control: no-cache"
        ],
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    return $response; 
}

$origin = "75 9th Ave, New York, NY";
$destination = "MetLife Stadium Dr East Rutherford, NJ 07073";

$directions = directionGet($origin, $destination);
```

---

You ask me about what's wrong in your code 
The answer are
1. I change http to https
2. I add modify your header (remove post header because it's use get method)
3. I encode string in url format (urlencode)

I modify your code for example

```
function directionGet($origin, $destination) {
    $callToGoogle = curl_init();
    $googleApiKey = '*************************';

    curl_setopt_array(
      $callToGoogle,
      array (
          CURLOPT_URL => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='. urlencode($origin).'&destination=' . urlencode($destination) . '&mode=driving&key=' . $googleApiKey,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($callToGoogle);
    curl_close($callToGoogle);
    return $response; 
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: It worked! What i was doing wrong? i'm new to cURL so i'd be happy to learn

Comment: I add the answer in old post